# How to create a new field in firestore using cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am a newbie in cloud functions. I want to create a new field `counter` whenever a document is created.

I tried the following codes:

```
exports.createCounter = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate((snap, 
 context) => {
  console.log('onCreate created');

      return snap.data.ref.set({counter: 0}, {merge: true})
            .then(() => {
               console.log("Count is created! "+userId);
             })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Counter Error writing document: ", error);
             });
    });
```

and using `firebase-admin`:

```
exports.createCounter = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const id = context.params.userId;
  console.log('onCreate created');
  return admin.firestore().collection('users')
  .doc(id).set({counter: 0}, {merge: true})
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written! "+id);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });
});
```

But both are not triggered when a new document is created.

**UPDATE**

At first, I create `users/userId/collection/doc`. When it is created, I want to add a `counter` field into `users/userId`

Comment: Hi @Marat, have you seen this **[Setting Data to Firestore with Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51346959/setting-data-to-firestore-with-cloud-functions-in-js?rq=1)?**, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @sllopis. On that page, it is created a new collection. But I want to create a new field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update following your comment**

You can add a field to the `users/userId` document when you create a doc under the `users/userId/theCollection` collection by modifying the code of the second solution presented below.

Just trigger at the level of the subcollection, get the parent document `id` through the `context` object and build its `DocumentReference`based on this `id`, as follows:

```
exports.createCounter = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/theCollection/{docId}').onCreate((snap,
    context) => {

    const id = context.params.userId;

    return admin.firestore().collection('users')
        .doc(id).set({ counter: 0 }, { merge: true })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Count is created! " + userId);
            return null;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Counter Error writing document: ", error);
            return null;
        });
});
```

---

**Initial answer**

The following should do the trick:

```
exports.createCounter = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate((snap, 
 context) => {
      console.log('onCreate created');

      const docRef = snap.ref;

      return docRef.set({counter: 0}, {merge: true})
          .then(() => {
               console.log("Count is created! "+userId);
               return null;
           })
          .catch((error) => {
               console.error("Counter Error writing document: ", error);
               return null;
           });
    });
```

Note that instead of doing `snap.data.ref` to get the [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) you have to do `snap.ref`. As a matter of fact, `snap` is a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) and you need to use its `ref` property.

---

Your second code snippet should normally work, but you need to return a value in the `then()` and in the `catch()` to indicate to the Cloud Function platform that the work of the function is complete. Note that you need to do the same thing for the above code. I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ which explain this key point.

```
exports.createCounter = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const id = context.params.userId;
  console.log('onCreate created');
  return admin.firestore().collection('users')
  .doc(id).set({counter: 0}, {merge: true})
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written! "+id);
    return null;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      return null;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check it. Which one is better?

Comment: Is the function triggered immediately after deploying it? If so, unfortunately the first one didn't work

Comment: Good question. I would say the first one since the `DocumentReference` is immediately available through the `snapshot`. While with the second approach you need to call the `collection()` and `doc()` methods.

Comment: "unfortunately the first one didn't work" -> It should. Let me check by testing it in my environment.

Comment: It seems to work if there is no collection in `userId`. I am so sorry that I haven't mentioned: at first, I create `users/userId/collection/doc`. When it is created, I want to add a `counter` field into `users/userId`. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Ah ok! If I correctly understand this is totally different! Because if you create directly a doc in `users/userId/collection/` it will **NOT** create a `user` doc (if this one does not exist). Therefore your Cloud Function will not be triggered. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761254/firestore-oncreate-not-triggered-when-creation-is-done-by-a-sub-document-or-coll/56761400#56761400

Comment: I confirm that if you create a `user` in the `users` collection, it does work.

Comment: So there is no way to add a new field into `users/userId`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201330/discussion-between-marat-and-renaud-tarnec).